# How can I convert this into data-attributes?

Tags: html, dtd, custom-data-attribute

I'm confused with data-attributes and my task is to convert this into a html5 valid code:

```
<xy:search campaign="campaign-name" width="280px" height="32px">
</xy:search>
```

This is an advertisement and recently we wanted to validate our page but this is the last error I couldn't fix, because of the custom dtd element.

I don't want to write custom dtd file, and yes, this code must be work exactly like before changes, they have a script for this custom element, so I just want to modify the base code and "translate" it to the validator, so the element must be visible/readable somehow for the advertisor's script.

I think it can be solved with html5 data-attributes, but I don't know that method...

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: `data-*` attributes are just attributes; you will need code that manipulates it.

Comment: I tried to read about some jquery modification with the base code, but I don't know jquery that much to find out the exact way with this issue, I saw some different codes. Basically I think I need to use a jquery code to replace the custom XY element, then add data-attribute to validate the campaign attribute. Am I close? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `campaign` it the only attribute you need to convert...  it is as simple as prepending `data-` to the attribute.  That's all a data attribute is.  Example:

```
<xy:search data-campaign="campaign-name" width="280px" height="32px">
```

And then to access the value in something like jQuery, you would use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
$("your element").data("campaign"); // getter
$("your element").data("campaign","new value"); // setter
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, finally I realized if I use the jquery append function to insert the ad code, the validator will pass it as it was and the advertisement works fine too. :)